# Indent fancy quotation box in latex

Tags: indentation, quoting

I want to write latex to implement below fancy quotation box as per solution [Fancy Quotation Boxes in Latex](http://www.jevon.org/wiki/Fancy_Quotation_Boxes_in_Latex).

[image]

However, I don't know how to indent the quotation box such as:

[image]

You may observe the quotes **part of definition D** has been indented, so it aligns with **Definition D**.

I update the code:

```
% <!-- language: latex --> Comment this line for avoid errors
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}    

%Defining colour with different models.
\definecolor{mypink1}{rgb}{0.858, 0.188, 0.478}
\definecolor{mypink2}{RGB}{219, 48, 122}
\definecolor{mypink3}{cmyk}{0, 0.7808, 0.4429, 0.1412}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}

\definecolor{formalshade}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,1}    

\newenvironment{formal}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{%
    \hspace{1pt}%
    {\color{mygray}\vrule width 6pt}%
    {\color{formalshade}\vrule width 4pt}%
    \colorbox{formalshade}%
  }%
  \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
  \noindent\hspace{-4.55pt}% disable indenting first paragraph
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{7pt}%
  \vspace{2pt}\vspace{2pt}%
}
{%
  \vspace{2pt}\end{adjustwidth}\endMakeFramed%
}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Definition Lists}

\textbf{Markdown Extra} has a special syntax for definition lists too: \newline

\noindent
\textbf{Term 1} \\
\noindent
\textbf{Term 2} \\
\indent \indent Definition A \\
\indent \indent Definition B \\

\noindent
\textbf{Term 3} \\

\indent \indent Definition C \\

\indent \indent Definition D \\

% indent quote blocks?
\begin{formal}
    part of definition D
\end{formal}    

\begin{formal}
\begin{quote}
    part of definition D
\end{quote}
\end{formal}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you bring us a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with the code of your document for see what are you trying to do. Otherwise the question is very general and let people on the forum all the work and effort.

Comment: You can replace \indent with \hspace{0.2in} (for example)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I saw the page from where you took the code, I see what you do and... perhaps the `list` environment can be useful in this case. From the code of your MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}    

%Defining colour with different models.
\definecolor{mypink1}{rgb}{0.858, 0.188, 0.478}
\definecolor{mypink2}{RGB}{219, 48, 122}
\definecolor{mypink3}{cmyk}{0, 0.7808, 0.4429, 0.1412}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.8}

\definecolor{formalshade}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,1}    

\newenvironment{formal}{
  \def\FrameCommand{
    \hspace{1pt}
    {\color{mygray}\vrule width 6pt}
    {\color{formalshade}\vrule width 4pt}
    \colorbox{formalshade}
  }
  \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}
  \noindent\hspace{-4.55pt}% disable indenting first paragraph
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{7pt}
  \vspace{2pt}\vspace{2pt}
}
{
  \vspace{2pt}\end{adjustwidth}\endMakeFramed
}

\newcounter{definitio}    

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Definition Lists}

\textbf{Markdown Extra} has a special syntax for definition lists too: \newline

\begin{list}{\textbf{Term} \textbf{\arabic{definitio}}}{\usecounter{definitio}\setlength{\labelwidth}{42.5pt}}
  \item bla bla bla
  \item bla bla bla
  \begin{list}{Definition \Alph{definitio}}{\usecounter{definitio}\setlength{\labelwidth}{60pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{56pt}}
    \item  
    \item
  \end{list}
  \item  bla bla bla
  \begin{list}{Definition \Alph{definitio}}{\usecounter{definitio}\setlength{\labelwidth}{60pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{56pt}}
    \item  
    \item 
  \end{list}
\end{list}

% indent quote blocks?

\begin{formal}
    part of definition D
\end{formal} 

\begin{formal}
  \begin{list}{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{60pt}\setlength{\leftmargin}{56pt}}
    \item  part of definition D
  \end{list}
\end{formal}

\end{document}
```

As you can see I was trying to rebuild your MWE using `list` environment. Unfortunately the result is not exactly what you want. But I see the environment can help you with the indentation building nested environments with few adjustments in the `formal` environment I think.

The `list` environment is the base for the listing environments such as `itemize` or `enumerate` and works in the following way:

```
\begin{list}{label}{format parameters}
\item First item
\item Second item
    .
    .
    . 
\item Last item
\end{list}
```

where:

- `label` *specifies how items should be labeled. This argument is a

  piece of text that is inserted in a box to form the label. This

  argument can and usually does contain other `LaTeX` commands*.
- `format parameters` *contains commands to change the spacing
  parameters for the list. An empty argument will select all default

  spacing which should suffice for most cases. The format parameters

  are:*
- `\itemsep`
- `\labelsep`
- `\labelwidth`
- `\leftmargin`
- `\listparindent`
- `\parsep`
- `\parskip`
- `\partopsep`
- `\rightmargin`
- `\topsep`

Also you can create a new counter for automatic numbering, I used one in the preamble `\newcounter{definitio}` and I used again to define how to use it in the `label` argument of the `list` environments I used.

Anyway, I couldn't pause and restart the numbering of definitions as you did in your MWE. I can think that the counter `\value` can be used for this, but I have not tried. You can read more about counters [here](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/counters.htm).

Comment: [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) is a good Markdown Editor. I want to learn how it export to PDF format. Markdown -> Latex -> PDF, I don't think so. Please check subsubsection `### Definition Lists` where I would like to reference.