# Indent fancy quotation box in latex without list

Tags: formatting, indentation, quoting, box, quotation

I would like to create a box with the format of a [Fancy Box](https://jevon.org/wiki/Fancy_Quotation_Boxes_in_Latex), but the indentation of a `quote` environment. I have found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197650/indent-fancy-quotation-box-in-latex) question, which concerns a similar problem, however the solution given in this thread is not particularly useful for my case.

What I would like to do is modify the `formal` environment such that it is indented in the same way as the `quote` environment. Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Formal Quotation Boxes
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% for adjustwidth environment
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

% for formal definitions
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


% environment derived from framed.sty: see leftbar environment definition
\definecolor{formalshade}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,1}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.93}

\newenvironment{formal}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{%
    \hspace{1pt}%
    {\color{mygray}\vrule width 2pt}%
    {\color{lightgray}\vrule width 4pt}%
    \colorbox{lightgray}%
  }%
  \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
  \noindent\hspace{-4.55pt}% disable indenting first paragraph
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{7pt}%
  \vspace{2pt}\vspace{2pt}%
}
{%
  \vspace{2pt}\end{adjustwidth}\endMakeFramed%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque.


\begin{formal}
     Eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Semper eget duis at tellus at. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus. Augue neque gravida in fermentum. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor.
\end{formal}

Diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit.

\begin{quote}
Nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. Eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you want like with a hand drawn image or something? So you want to shift right the "background box" so that the bold gray bar on the left are shifted a bit to the right?

Comment: If you edit `\hspace{1pt}` to `\hspace{1cm}` would that be what you want?

Comment: Yes! That was easy, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as an answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Formal Quotation Boxes
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% for adjustwidth environment
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

% for formal definitions
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


% environment derived from framed.sty: see leftbar environment definition
\definecolor{formalshade}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,1}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.93}

\newenvironment{formal}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{%
    \hspace{1cm}%  ← change this to modify the indentation ========================
    {\color{mygray}\vrule width 2pt}%
    {\color{lightgray}\vrule width 4pt}%
    \colorbox{lightgray}%
  }%
  \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
  \noindent\hspace{-4.55pt}% disable indenting first paragraph
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{7pt}%
  \vspace{2pt}\vspace{2pt}%
}
{%
  \vspace{2pt}\end{adjustwidth}\endMakeFramed%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin. Id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque.


\begin{formal}
     Eget est lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Semper eget duis at tellus at. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus. Augue neque gravida in fermentum. Quam nulla porttitor massa id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi. Duis at tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque. Porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor.
\end{formal}

Diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare. Erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem mollis aliquam. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices. Turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit.

\begin{quote}
Nec ultrices dui sapien eget mi proin. Penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris. Nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. Eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis.
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Output looks like this.

[image: output]

Comment: By the way it's also possible to change the inner `\begin{adjustwidth}...\end{adjustwidth}` to plain form, although the lack of the additional group might break something else.  → [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but an unexpected problem just occurred: Footnotes within the 
`formal` environment are not printed in the output. Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: The reason is [glossaries - footnote inside mbox - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104543/footnote-inside-mbox). Use footnotemark and footnotetext as instructed there.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful!